# printing .eps to .pdf using cups

Tags: drivers, printing, pdf, cups-lpd, eps

I want to print a .eps file to a pdf file using cups.

I have done a basic install along with `printer-driver-cups-pdf` and `printer-driver-all` (I assume one covers the other, but included for clarity)

I have also configured a pdf printer in the ui which I've named `cups_pdf`.

```
printf "hello world" | lp -d cups_pdf
```

that command seems to work as I get a pdf in my `~/PDF` folder with the content *hello world*.

however when I try to print an eps file I am just getting a blank page without any errors (that I can find)

```
lp ./file.eps -d cups_pdf
```

is it more difficult than I imagine to print a .eps file, or am I missing something?